# Image loader animation for Large Images

Tags: css, ajax, image, preloader

I have some high-res images in a gallery on my site, and all I want some sort of animation like what can be found at [ajaxload.info](http://ajaxload.info), to display in place of my image until it is fully loaded. Some its suggest its as simple as adding something like this to your css:

```
img { background:url('../images/ajax-loader.gif') center center no-repeat;}
```

Well for one this adds this background image to my transparent 'spacer.gif' resulting in the loading image showing up where my spacer is.  However this 'method' doesn't even work to begin with.  When I view the high-res images they still load from top to bottom, and I don't even see the loader.gif. Any help?  I thought there was information on this everywhere, but for the life of me I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

just give all the high res images a class and then in the css use the class name instead of the global img tag to have the background set to.

If you use jquery to load the images then the images won't load from the top down but will only appear when it's fully loaded, so the background loader image will be visible and once the image has fully loaded and is displayed the loader will be covered. This method works pefectly as it's so simple, you were probably just missing something out.

Comment: hmm I dont know jquery... whats the simplest way to load an image via jquery? I know that the .load() doesnt work for cached images...